# How to get details info about pokemons in pokeAPI

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, rest

I recently started to learn react. I am making a pokedex app with pokeAPI.
On the card I need to get the type of each pokemon. Below is an example of how I get and save pokemon data.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const endpointForPokemonInfo = `${pokemonUrl}`;
    fetchPokemon(endpointForPokemonInfo); // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  const fetchPokemon = endpointForPokemonInfo => {
    fetch(endpointForPokemonInfo)
      .then(result => result.json())
      .then(result => {
        setPokemon([...Pokemon, result.results]);
      }, setLoadingForPokemon(false))
      .catch(error => console.error("Error:", error));
  };
```

This is example how I display type of pokemon.

```
      {Pokemon &&
        Pokemon.map((types, id) => (
          <React.Fragment key={id}>
            <div
              style={{
                color: "#333",
                padding: 5,
                maxWidth: 100,
                display: "inline-block"
              }}
            >
              {types.type.name}
            </div>
          </React.Fragment>
        ))}
```

I don’t know what the problem is, but it throws an error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
    at GridCards.js:50
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at GridCards (GridCards.js:46)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14803)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:17034)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18610)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23203)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22154)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22130)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:21756)
    at react-dom.development.js:11089
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:653)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11039)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:11084)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:11072)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21199)
    at dispatchAction (react-dom.development.js:15660)
    at GridCards.js:23
```

If I `console.log(result)` or `console.log(...Pokemon)`, console shows this result

[console.log(result)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPp9f.png)

Comment: What do you get as value of `console.log(result.results)` ?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava hmmmm, 12 undefined

Comment: What is the value of `types`? Can you guard against this being undefined?
My bet, `{types.type.name}` is failing for you.

Comment: What about `console.log(result)` then? Perhaps you picked the wrong property in the response? (You could also inspect the response in the browser DevTools' network tab by filtering for „XHR” (old term for AJAX/fetch requests).

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I changed to the "result", and I get the object of details info, but this does not work to display

Comment: Post the structure of `results` in the question

Comment: @Ryuno-Ki
console.log(result) displayed object of pokemon details. I suspected, that types.type.name is not true . But I dont know why.

Comment: Until you post the `results` variable in your question, people have no choice but to keep guessing, you may not find an answer at all

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I added link to screenshot of console.log(result) in the bottom of post. Its here: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPp9f.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPp9f.png).
Or, may be, you mean some another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the results structure, it is clear that `Pokemon.types` is also an array, so you need to use `.map()` once more:

```
{ 
  Pokemon &&
  Pokemon.map((types, id) => (
    <React.Fragment key={id}>
      {
        types.map((currType, typeId) => (        
          <div
            key={typeId}
            style={{
              color: "#333",
              padding: 5,
              maxWidth: 100,
              display: "inline-block"
            }}
          >
            {currType.type.name}
          </div>
        ))
      }
    </React.Fragment>
  ))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setPokemon([...Pokemon, result.types]);
```

should set Pokemon: [result.types]

which should set Pokemon as the array result.types

you'll have to iterate with the map function as you have

```
{Pokemon &&
        Pokemon.map((types, id) => (

          <React.Fragment key={id}>
            <div
              style={{
                color: "#333",
                padding: 5,
                maxWidth: 100,
                display: "inline-block"
              }}
            >
              {type.name}
            </div>
          </React.Fragment>
        ))}
```

should iterate and map each type.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: its doesnt work for me. It say, that `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Comment: @Valeriy Samoilov do you get the same values when you console.log(Pokemon)?  If you have any questions of the above code snippet don't hesistate to ask.

Comment: @Dharman Thanks, I'll keep that in mind I'll continue to update as trying to help provide a solution.  I'll update my answer as I get more information.

Comment: @DcoderZ if I console.log(...Pokemon), that was same values.

Comment: @ValeriySamoilov if you run console.log(types) within the fragment is it logging an array or an object?

Comment: @DcoderZ If it `console.log(types)` -  array, but if it `console.log(...Pokemon) - its an object.`

Comment: @ValeriySamoilov I updated the code snippet can you try that and see if it works?

Comment: @DcoderZ Yes, I tried. But it doesn't work too. It doing no one error.
Also I changed `types` to `type`.